# Extends and Interface has same method with the same parameters but different return types

Tags: java

In java I have to create a class that extends another class and implements an interface. This is the class I have to extend

```
public class Cell  {

    public void receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {     
    
    } 
}
```

This is the interface that I have to implement

```
public interface HoleInterface {    
    public int[] receiveRat(RatInterface pRat);
}
```

I have made the class

```
public class Hole extends Cell  implements HoleInterface {

    public Hole() {
    
    }

    @Override
    public int[] receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;    
    }
```

The int[] in the hole class doesn't work because Hole extends the Cell and Cell has a method like that with the return type void. What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Q: What do you *WANT* to do?  If "Cell.receiveRat()" and "HoleInterface.receiveRat()" are two different things, then why don't you give one of them a different name?

Comment: It's an assignment and I can't change the names. What I want is to know if I'm doing something wrong or is there nothing I can do and only change the names?

Comment: A class in Java can not implement two methods with identical signature (i.e. name + parameter list) but different return types. Note that the JVM itself doesn't have a problem with *loading and using* these kinds of classes, but the Java *language* has no explicit way to construct them (even though it sometimes creates synthetic methods that break this rule).

Comment: So is the only thing I can do to change the name of one of the methods?

Comment: This is something that you should talk to your teacher about. Now, if possible.

Comment: If Cell's `receiveRat()` method returns void, then nothing is currently using whatever is being returned, so you can change it to return `int[]` and nothing will break, so I would do that.

Comment: @paulsm4 no, it won’t shadow it, it will *override* it. Methods can’t shadow, only fields can.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that is not possible. The return types clash. What you could do, is either rename one of the methods to something like `public void getRat(RatInterface pRat){...}` or let Cell implement HoleInterface, removing the `public void receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {...}` method and replacing it with the `@Override public int[] receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {...}` method. If then Hole extends Cell, it indirectly also implements HoleInterface. Like this:

```
public class Cell implements HoleInterface {
    @Override
    public int[] receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {
        return null;
    }
```

```
//Now indirectly implements HoleInterface through Cell
public class Hole extends Cell{
    public Hole() {
    
    }
    @Override
    public int[] receiveRat(RatInterface pRat) {
        return null;    
    }
```

But thats just an idea... How to fix your problem depends on the specific task or problem you want to solve.

Comment: Since this is a class assignment, and the OP says he/she was given those requirements: the correct approach is *TO ASK THE INSTRUCTOR* for clarification.  I'm guessing the OP probably misunderstood something...